# Symfony users providers : FOS + SSO with metadata

Tags: php, symfony, single-sign-on, metadata, fosuserbundle

I've made a multisite app with classic FOSUserBundle provider.
Each user is linked to a site by a ManyToOne relation between User and Site entity.

My point : I'm asked now to setup a SSO system on a per-site basis. Although it seems pretty clear that I can mix providers for authentication (and then having FOS + SSO), **how can I handle possible metadata linked to user cleared by SSO, such as site belonging information?**

- Should I create a user copy when cleared by SSO on my system (and then "break" SSO logic)?
- Should I have to add this data on my User entity on-the-fly after SSO clearance?

Thank you for your answers,

Regards,

Comment: after successful login the IDP  basically would return some attributes that are related to the user , i would parse those attributes and add them on User entity

Comment: Hi, my point is merely about other entities that are user entity related. On an external access provider POV, AFAIK user will not really exist on system. So how persist actions he can do?